# approximation of a trigonometric sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, summation, approximation

I have a trigonometric sum as below
$$\frac{1}{N^2}\sum_{r=0}^{N-1}\frac{\sin^2(\pi e)}{\sin^2(\frac{\pi(r-n+e))}{N})}\frac{\cos^2(\frac{\pi(Ne-e-r+n)}{N})}{\cos^2(\frac{\pi(Ne-e)}{N})}$$
and I want to show analytically that for small $e$ ($e<0.2$) and large $N$ the above sum approximately equals $1$.   I have showed this numerically in MATLAB but I cant show it analytically. By the way $n$ is an integer between $0$ and $N-1$.

Can any one help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a difference between $n$ and $N$ or a typo ?

Comment: They are different. $n$ is an integer between $0$ and $N-1$.

Comment: Use Taylor series, I think